# iPad issues with Menu and Sub Menus

Tags: css, ipad

I have menus and sub menus for my desktop website. Sub menu appears on hover of menus. Menus having blank  tags on it as only sub menus having respective linked pages. It is working fine with desktop.

When are accessing same in iPad, clicking on menu shows sub menu but same page redirected to href link from first submenu. We just want to open sub menu instead of page redirection.

We can not remove blank  tags from menu as it stops showing sub menus in iPad.

Is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your menu looks like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/">Menu Level 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Menu Level 2</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Try something like the following in your jQuery "document ready" code:

```
if ('ontouchstart' in window || 'ontouch' in window) {
  $('ul > li > a').on('touchstart',function(e){
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('touchOpen')) {
      $('li.touchOpen').removeClass('touchOpen');
      $(this).parent().addClass('touchOpen');
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

It will bind an event when the link from the top menu is touched, that checks if the link's parent LI has a specified class. If it does have the class, then nothing happens (i.e. the user will follow through to the new page). If it doesn't have the class, then the class is added, and the link isn't followed through.

Then you just need to add the "touchOpen" class along with your :hover css;

```
li:focus ul,
li:hover ul,
li:active ul,
.touchOpen ul{
 /* css code to display the sub menu */
}
```